# Двоеточие при указании на следствие

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие

В "Обломове" Гончаров употребил двоеточие при указании на следствие от совершенного действия. Не корректнее ли использовать тире?

> Но мужики пошли и сажен за пятьдесят до места стали окликать чудовище разными голосами: ответа не было...

Comment: Следствие может быть при следующей интерпретации: *Из-за того, что мужики пошли и сажен за пятьдесят до места стали окликать чудовище разными голосами, ответа не было.*

Comment: Пример со следствием: *Они тихо окликнули чудовище — ответа не было.*

Comment: По-моему, в этому примере тоже следствие неочевидно. Ответа могло не быть не по причине обращения мужиков к животному, а по причине его отсутствия в данном месте в данный момент, например.

Comment: Вы правы. Этот пример рассчитан на то, что чудовище там было, иначе тире не подходит (а нужно "а"). Всё дело в том, что необходима **причинно**-следственная связь. В таких случаях можно подставить "из-за того, что" или "вследствие чего".

Comment: Даже если чудовище там было, причины могут быть различные: например, оно крепко спит или неживое.

Comment: Это да, в таких случаях тире не должно стоять. Оно к месту, лишь если тихий окрик является причиной.

Comment: @ВладимирЖеребцов Владимир, если Вы цитируете Гончарова, то **неполное** предложение нужно оформлять с многоточием: *Но мужики пошли и сажен за пятьдесят до места стали окликать чудовище разными голосами: ответа не было...* Потому что полное вот такое: *Но мужики пошли и сажен за пятьдесят до места стали окликать чудовище разными голосами: ответа не было; они остановились; потом опять двинулись.* Или такое: *Но мужики пошли и сажен за пятьдесят до места стали окликать чудовище разными голосами: ответа не было, они остановились, потом опять двинулись.*

Answer (score 2):

Каждый знак препинания – это не только условный знак, поставленный по правилам, но еще и  определенная интонация и свой оттенок семантического значения. Поэтому надо с уважением относиться  к авторской речи, стараясь ее понять.

1. **Хотим поставить тире?** Правила позволяют это сделать, тем более что простые предложения в составе БСП имеют здесь разную структуру. Кроме того,  можно использовать сочинительную связь с союзом НО, а это как бы противопоставление (окликнули, но ответа не услышали).

Значение **следствия**? Но здесь нет такого значения.

2. **Но автор поставил двоеточие**, а почему?  Двоеточие обозначает  неполное понижение голоса и подчеркнутую паузу: окликнули чудовище – и прислушались. Автор как бы предлагает читателям немного помолчать и прислушаться вместе  с ними.
3. У **тире**  же нет такой интонации (не подходит для этого ни разделительное, ни присоединительное тире). А **точка с запятой** – это вообще почти точка, у этого знака своя область применения.

Comment: «А точка с запятой – это вообще почти точка, у этого знака своя область применения» — вот-вот. Данный случай как раз из этой области.

Comment: У этих знаков интонация похожа, только у точки более длительная пауза. Но в обоих случаях ПОЛНОЕ понижение тона (как бы окончание фразы). А этого не должно быть. Здесь семантика такая: послушали, еще послушали, но ничего не услышали. Двоеточие обозначает НЕПОЛНОЕ понижение тона, оно предупреждает о том, что будет продолжение (интонационное ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ, как называет это Розенталь).

Comment: «Но в обоих случаях ПОЛНОЕ понижение тона (как бы окончание фразы). А этого не должно быть». — Какое «полное понижение тона» после точки с запятой?! Sharon, вы меня не на шутку изумили. «Двоеточие обозначает НЕПОЛНОЕ понижение тона, оно предупреждает о том, что будет продолжение» — не двоеточие. Именно так работает точка с запятой.

Comment: Ссылочку на источник, пожалуйста.  У меня  есть ссылка на двоеточие (из грамматики), а  что есть у вас?

Comment: Ссылочку на источник чего?

Comment: Вашей информации, конечно.   Что именно такой интонации соответствует точка с запятой.  Где вы это прочитали? И как вы понимаете интонационное предупреждение по Розенталю?

Comment: Про «интонацию, которой соответствует» точка с запятой я не писал. Я написал, что точка с запятой так — т. е. в качестве предупреждения о продолжении фразы — РАБОТАЕТ. И я должен заметить, что точка с запятой (как и запятая) — знак ПРЕПИНАНИЯ, а не интонации. А в каких случаях этот знак ставится в русском языке, можно почитать, например, здесь (пункт 1): https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9

Comment: Я только Розенталя читаю. Значит, знаки препинания не связаны с интонацией?  Кстати, интонация – это основной вид связи в БСП.  Ну да ладно, перейдем на грамматический язык.  ТОЧКА С ЗАПЯТОЙ ставится между однородными по смыслу предложениями при наличии  следующих факторов:  (1) значительная распространенность; (2) наличие собственных знаков препинания; (3) отдалённость тематики; (4) необходимость смыслового разграничения предложений. У ВАС КАКОЙ ФАКТОР? Неужели отдаленность тематики?  Вот это меня больше всего беспокоит – хотелось бы обозначить взаимосвязь, но  только не отдаленность.

Comment: «Я только Розенталя читаю» — и очень зря: он не обо всём успел написать. «Значит, знаки препинания не связаны с интонацией?» — отчасти связаны. «У ВАС КАКОЙ ФАКТОР?» — распространённость первого предложения. «Хотелось бы обозначить взаимосвязь, но только не отдаленность» — отдалённость обозначает точка. Теоретически и её можно было бы поставить после первого предложения и начать второе с прописной буквы, но мне тоже хочется больше связи между предложениями. Но не такой тесной связи, чтобы фразу предлагалось выпалить на одном дыхании. Итак: не точка, не запятая, остаётся — что?

Comment: Остается двоеточие.  Поставите точку – будет парцелляция, поставите точку с запятой –  будет почти парцелляция, а нам это нужно?   Распространенность, говорите? Тогда я лично вам посвящаю следующий свой вопрос – задам его позже. Приведу пример, где распространенности хоть отбавляй, а точки с запятой нет, да и двоеточия тоже. Формальный у вас, однако, подход – тонкости ощущений не хватает. Распространенность учитывается, когда она связана со смысловой неоднозначностью или трудностью в понимании структуры предложения – здесь же этого нет.

Comment: А Розенталя я читаю, потому что он ближе всего  к официальным правилам (в редакции 1956 года), и а него можно ссылаться. А то вы мне предложите какой-нибудь левый источник из Сети и будете уверять, что это истинно так.

Comment: Sharon, в левом источнике тоже может содержаться истина: дух дышит где хочет. А якобы авторитетные источники могут с умным видом нести несусветную чушь (это я не о Розентале).

Comment: «Формальный у вас, однако, подход – тонкости ощущений не хватает» — не вам бы так говорить :))

Comment: Тише (шепотом). Так нельзя говорить - это переход на личности :)  Конец связи.

Comment: «Остается двоеточие» — причинно-следственная связь? :) «Поставите точку с запятой – будет почти парцелляция, а нам это нужно» — именно это и нужно.

Comment: «это переход на личности :) » — Да? Тогда зачем же вы перешли?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы поставил точку с запятой.